# Estimating a dependent variable when given with a number of independent variables

Tags: python, linear-regression, curve-fitting, non-linear-regression

I am given a dataset ( GRE scores, TOEFL, University ranking, SOP, LOR, CGPA, Research) and I have to estimate chance of admit of a student based on these numbers. However I have to do it without any libraries (just numpy is allowed). Hence I don't need an exactor close answer.Only approach is enough.
(Can we use multiple linear regression since we don't exactly know the relation between the variables beforehand?)

I tried linear regression, but then coefficient for GRE score came to be negative (which doesn't make sense)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.